# mysql prepared Select statement join not working

Tags: php, html, select, prepared-statement

So my prepared statement works and all but I dont know how to tell the php to join the two columns.

I have tried an unprepared statement and that works. I have tried adding more variables to bind_results.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "Select tblcategory.CategoryName as catname,tblcategory.id as catid, tblwritter.Writter as writtername, tblwritter.writterdescription as writterdescription, tblwritter.PostingDate as writterpostingdate, tblwritter.UpdationDate as writterupdationdate, tblwritter.WritterId as writterid from  tblwritter join tblcategory on  tblwritter.CategoryId=tblcategory.id where  tblwritter.Is_Active=1 and  WritterId=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $writterid);
$writterid=intval($_GET['scid']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($catname,$catid,$writtername,$writterdescription,$writterpostingdate,$writterupdationdate,$writterid);
$stmt->fetch();

                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Category</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                                      <select class="form-control" name="category" required>
                                                   <option value="<?php echo $catid;?>"><?php echo $catname;?></option>
<?php
$stmt = $con -> prepare('select id,CategoryName from  tblcategory where Is_Active=?');
$stmt -> bind_param('i', $Is_Active);
$Is_Active = 1;
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($id, $CategoryName);
$stmt -> fetch(); 
// Feching active categories
$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select id,CategoryName from  tblcategory where Is_Active=1");
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
{    
?>
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result['id']);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result['CategoryName']);?></option>
<?php } ?>

                                                        </select> 
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

The expected results of this is the categories are supposes to drop down to edit the categories.

Comment: Is the first query working ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is Unclear because you failed to isolate where exactly your code is failing and haven't told us what error you are receiving.  (until that changes, I can not upvote your question)

Your question is clear about the desired effect though.  I have whipped up an untested script that I *believe* should work as required.

```
<?php
$config = ['localhost', 'root', '', 'dbname'];
if (!$con = new mysqli(...$config)) {
    die("MySQL Connection Error: <b>Check config values</b>");  // $con->connect_error
}

$query = "SELECT cat.CategoryName, cat.id,
                 writ.Writter, writ.writterdescription,
                 writ.PostingDate, writ.UpdationDate, writ.WritterId
          FROM tblwritter AS writ
          JOIN tblcategory AS cat ON writ.CategoryId = cat.id
          WHERE writ.Is_Active = 1
            AND writ.WritterId = ?"
if (!$stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    echo "Prepare Error: ";  // $con->error
} elseif (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET['scid']) ||
          !$stmt->execute() ||
          !$stmt->bind_result($catname,
                              $catid,
                              $writtername,
                              $writterdescription,
                              $writterpostingdate,
                              $writterupdationdate,
                              $writterid)) {
    echo "Statement Error: "; // $stmt->error
} elseif (!$stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "[No qualifying row found]";
}
$stmt->close();

$catid = $catid ?? 0;

$query = "SELECT id, CategoryName
          FROM tblcategory
          WHERE Is_Active = 1
            AND id != ?";
if (!$stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    echo "Prepare Error: "; // $con->error
} elseif (!$stmt->bind_param("i", $catid) ||
          !$stmt->execute() ||
          !$stmt->bind_result($id, $name)) {
    echo "Statement Error: "; // $stmt->error
} else { ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Category</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" name="category" required>
                <?php
                if ($catid) {
                    echo '<option value=' , $catid , '>' , htmlentities($catname) , '</option>';
                }
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo '<option value=' , $id , '>' , htmlentities($name) , '</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div> <?php
}
```

- Maintain object-oriented mysqli syntax instead of a mixture.  OO is my recommendation because it is less verbose than procedural.
- I have tabbed my snippet to make it all fit in the Stack Overflow snippet box without horizontal scrolling.
- Use ALL CAPS when writing MySQL keywords in your query -- this will improve readability.
- Use short table aliases (like "cat" and "writ" so that your query is less bloated with characters
- I have included a bunch of checkpoints in the processes to help you to diagnose any issues that may arise.  Never show raw error messages to the end user -- as a matter of security.
- I am not checking that `$_GET['scid']` exists, I am assuming you are doing this else where. If for some reason, a scid value is submitted that doesn't return any qualifying rows, then default it to zero.  This will allow the next query to work consistently.
- I altered your second query so that it doesn't offer the scid value a second time in the select field.
- If the $catid is found in the database, it will be presented as the first option in the select field.
- The integer values that are written as the `value` attribute in the options tags does not need `htmlentities()` as long as the database column is an INT data type (and it should be).  I also removed the double quoting on the integers because they are not necessary.